# Unable to start angular4 app using ng serve

Tags: node.js, angular

I am executing following command in my angular 4 app,

```
ng serve
```

But i am getting the following error message,

> This version of CLI is only compatible with angular version 2.3.1 or
>   better. Ple ase upgrade your angular version, e.g. by running:
>
> npm install @angular/core@latest

**my angular cli version is 1.6.8.**

Even i executed the above mentioned command to update my angular cli, but still same error is getting reported.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5558 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform Following steps:
1. perform npm cache clean --force
2. Reinstall Angular CLI globally using following command:
npm install -g @angular/cli
3. Delete 'node modules folder' and  perform npm install for your project and try running it with npm start/ng serve

Comment: thank you, this worked,.  Can you please explain the reason?

Comment: Some times due to cli version mismatching between global and local repo, this happens.

Answer (score 0):

From the github issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5558

The project needs a dev dependency for @angular/compiler-cli.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli@<your angular version>
```

If that doesnt work you can try this:

```
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@1.2.13
```

One of the main contributors of angular-cli said that it is an issue with older webpack versions, reading the github thread should provide some more insight

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the angular cli error, please try following steps :

- npm uninstall —save @angular/cli
- npm cache clean
- npm install —save @angular/cli